# Python JSON not breaking loop

Tags: python, json, musicbrainz

I am trying to use the MusicBrainz API via python and am having a harrowing time trying to figure out why my loop wont break after a certain condition is met. I am passing the duration of a song and the acoustic id via a URL that fetches JSON. I am not sure if the JSON is invaild, but am getting the formatted output to play with. The part where I am stuck is inspite of me telling the code to break when the duration of the song matches the duration of the returned JSON, it still continues to show the rest of the data that matched the duration. Also, I am getting a KeyError for one of the main data elements, which looks good to me! Please help!

Python Code being used:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import simplejson
import json
import pprint

duration = 266
output = 'AQABz0q6JJFknHgOHH0q9DyQw8lxIzmaLzl6HHyE7yO6G4dP9Mc3JDry4FJR5RfIvccWH0d_PD-O63gi9KTQPjme4-uDxl04hMqcQf0RfXgmKWDSDD8aF9dYTDl5hEPy46gnHY-iPEWZEWfw42

-

SIHZiQQ9xLR90ckzRw_mNez_aHZeeQnlIIdfxyHieBLl0HC_Y_Ajpo3lxnMf7DJUleJKGhk_Bw7mCvAqS53j1CE30BFdmYqeOL3pQ8vgeNAqzfKjMx_jRJ0dTMT_yZziuIE6ko1kSzcG7BMZzCU13JTglGZ9x

pcVJKgjlHAlfnFGONw8uHo-xd8Pn46DGDMmeI-fx5Vid6LjwXCLKh2h-5IPy8LiP3iUsaoGU9PixE3_wZEcyqw0O_MPhiugffMcfxNSJJMcbfMqagtMDH9eP5-AfJF-OMMtRUTl4JWiebA-

MnsazIzmDHP9QHU2DL-CTTMGHIfihXwqe6PjR_ugPnTlyXDmehGmCW5KDUHkO8Qg7HDPBJ8dP_MGlBHp-HD8uRuBewnoxvtCTwkvUCaeOH01MWA9ON0hupItyNJNSPELzZ-hFxAp1DXJ8nEolQu-

PtGLwED_gmMfzG3fw9Hhx3mhe1Do-o5KmVIG1M8MTIdmP8D_MMagTUsaP9sd_WKg-H6eRejm-J4TOHHPyEFVPkN9Ri-HA_A6aHlcu4Tn6KHiM99iRujGe42iO48eP-0WTRoOToxb-

o9nR99jR1EF_hImzrEEyJXyGiRnTwx8qo9E4H1VzPMKDvoMd-gjlLIS2C442UmhzDc-O-

kVDIdePZ0dvorlwZbrw5McTP5i8Hc1jXEH0vDiEP9ilK7iUQ6qkY3qQPsNFNJoY462JL_gZoTlC10geTc5xqRPxDMWOivIOMj_e402RPEGu4R2ancKfww9YJfB3CdP34D6eHiG1FXPESRxcHf6hPfh6nJskZH

Ke4DTW4w8-4wkf4sqHnkd6JCcuGl6SPCgZnMeYJiPuhbh1RGIeJMSN_3imwi4HeImeo5SOS7ij5HiMK7oQnhf0C-l0_KjUrPhx7_hxXDpC2IGmPMV_FT-

Rq8aTAukX_BfU_EXOxXCTLMQlC89yPPnRZEGeC82kRGSgMzx6Isx0Ia4uPJEY9PLR9Hg04w90mEN-CfuONvrhH4ezDQ8TjEeYc9CeHmGqHD8qZ4dVnEc_41R0NAqPaj2aNQ-eIm1zI-dxZzme-

HjQkuiLH36RM0j4oD8-EueDLjE8EvUyfBc-hhF-

C8n4IH1QncELRoFTgjADFCCKdIOIBYQZ0UABgDAnsAGCQuGEAgwhwACGDBFgMIIAAQKsMIQY4QARQFAAiJGeEQOoBEgpEZxQAAEipDAOEYCEAU4AZAEBQAoYDGFAMGKIwIIRgIg4jiDFlIAAIEIEBMwwBJQkX

hiohHEGIKAkcsIp4RAigAHBgPKSAKIIAoAxgJBjlhhkCIDAIAQkIgYAKSyQCDpCARIESWUAMYQ4YQGzGhhkADBAEOIEMAAhZRlQRgGkBBECMeAIQYAghxBAChAigANEIWKQcEbB5ZxlChGKACCAEKWEsIIyiw

RiTAABgBNKAAIIQMQhJCCoTAgliAIAICYwAIRZowRgxCllDBOAAEGABQIRoQ0ABIFgHCEECSEUMhQBAhkDwABCBANIACSABMxoAYGEBFRCASBEGAMBEMAIxBQQABkkLALAAIaIYIwggoACShgEjLEKAQ0AQsY

goBwAAImMFBBIQQUUQcgQARQI'
data = {}
data['client'] = '8XaBELgH'
data['format'] = 'json'
data['meta'] = '2'
data['duration'] = str(duration)
data['fingerprint'] = output
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup', urllib.urlencode(data))
str_to_load = resp.read()
json = simplejson.loads(str_to_load)
#pprint.pprint(json)
for result in json['results']:
    for recording in result['recordings']:
        for track in recording['tracks']:
            track_artist = ''
            for artist in track['artists']:
                try:
                    track_artist += repr(artist['name']) + ' '
                except:
                    track_artist = ''
            #print str(track['duration']) + '-' + track['medium']['release']['title'] + '-' + track['title'] + '-' + track_artist
            if str(track['duration']) == str(duration):
                print 'Matched:' + str(track['duration']) + '-' + track['medium']['release']['title'] + '-' + track['title'] + '-' + track_artist
                break
```

Returned JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "results": [{
        "recordings": [{
            "duration": 264,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 264,
                "position": 7,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "036ce98e-0397-4ddb-97ff-e6784fdd21a4",
                        "title": "Live in Paris"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 10,
                    "format": "CD"
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Sail On"
            }],
            "id": "0083c88e-1ca2-484e-b1ff-d384358942bb"
        }, {
            "duration": 268,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 268,
                "position": 12,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "9c0a98e8-da23-49cf-a6ae-df27340deebb",
                        "title": "Love Songs"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 16,
                    "format": "CD"
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "60d41417-feda-4734-bbbf-7dcc30e08a83",
                    "name": "Diana Ross"
                }, {
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Endless Love"
            }],
            "id": "07be8b05-a1cb-4e88-8217-2ef5e0dafcb3"
        }, {
            "duration": 267,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 267,
                "position": 2,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "a4c1dce4-0e16-483e-95de-aabff4378711",
                        "title": "Top 40 Hitdossier 1981-1982"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 20
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "60d41417-feda-4734-bbbf-7dcc30e08a83",
                    "name": "Diana Ross"
                }, {
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Endless Love"
            }],
            "id": "1fb13442-b0e7-4891-97de-255ba7e8730f"
        }, {
            "duration": 263,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 263,
                "position": 16,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "add4c09f-b9f3-4e3f-b36b-22f30309ce2b",
                        "title": "Steve Wright's Sunday Love Songs, Volume 2"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 22,
                    "format": "CD"
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "60d41417-feda-4734-bbbf-7dcc30e08a83",
                    "name": "Diana Ross"
                }, {
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Endless Love"
            }],
            "id": "20df4da3-005e-4bde-9337-46925e709110"
        }, {
            "duration": 264,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 264,
                "position": 2,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "d23d377b-b69a-424b-856c-b78dfde11feb",
                        "title": "Always And Forever (disc 1)"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 20,
                    "format": "CD"
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Endless Love"
            }],
            "id": "2cf76055-5a41-4a39-82ba-611b7142ab91"
        }, {
            "duration": 265,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 265,
                "position": 9,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "3bc3d08b-7e50-47d0-951d-de95a10e1ee8",
                        "title": "The Love Album II"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 20,
                    "format": "CD"
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "60d41417-feda-4734-bbbf-7dcc30e08a83",
                    "name": "Diana Ross"
                }, {
                    "id": "3cb25fb2-5547-4b05-adec-1a5e37830d46",
                    "name": "Lionel Richie"
                }],
                "title": "Endless Love"
            }],
            "id": "33f02920-5832-490d-bf5f-3cce793925bf"
        }....too big to display here..
```

Please dont mind me pasting the output here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops),

> The break statement, like in C, breaks out of the smallest enclosing
>   for or while loop.

In your case

```
for track in recording['tracks']:
```

Try putting your code in a function and use return:

```
def find_it(json, duration):
  for result in json['results']:
      for recording in result['recordings']:
          for track in recording['tracks']:
              track_artist = ''
              for artist in track['artists']:
                  try:
                      track_artist += repr(artist['name']) + ' '
                  except:
                      track_artist = ''
              #print str(track['duration']) + '-' + track['medium']['release']['title'] + '-' + track['title'] + '-' + track_artist
              if str(track['duration']) == str(duration):
                return track, track_artist
  return None, None

track, track_artist = find_it(json, duration)
print 'Matched:' + str(track['duration']) + '-' + track['medium']['release']['title'] + '-' + track['title'] + '-' + track_artist
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but the code erros with a KeyError for result[recordings'] making the function die. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "junk.py", line 21, in <module>
    for recording in result['recordings']:
KeyError: 'recordings'`

Comment: Just ran the full code and got the result `Matched:266-Anthology, Volume 2-Endless Love-'Diana Ross' 'Lionel Richie'`

Comment: @Rod is right. When I add `sys.exit()` in your code and make sure that there are no unescaped newlines in your acoustid-data a get the same output. You possibly get your KeyError when you have spaces or similar in your data, because then it won't match.